# How to find whats causing Circular Dependencies in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm receiving stacktraces of FCs but I can't reproduce the FCs. What am I missing?

In the java code some views are set to `View.GONE` or `View.VISIBLE` depending on the state of the app. In the `LayoutParams` I only change size and margins.

The 2 nestled `RelativeLayouts` are because the activity has a translucent theme, the second is for an alphafilter which can be applied by the user.

Any help would be great!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/FNContainer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/clr_background"
android:paddingTop="8dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/AlphaContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <xx.xxxxxx.guielements.Footer
        android:id="@+id/footerInclude"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <xx.xxxxxx.guielements.RoseImageView
        android:id="@+id/RoseView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/footerInclude"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBeschrijving"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <xx.xxxxxx.guielements.HmpImageView
        android:id="@+id/HmpView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvBeschrijving"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDistToEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/HmpView"
        android:text="TC Eind: 1253m"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSnelheid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:text="120"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSnelheidAanduiding"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvSnelheid"
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:text="km/u"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVavg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvSnelheidAanduiding"
        android:text="120"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVavgAanduiding"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvVavg"
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:text="Ø km/u"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVmaxOnderbord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footerInclude"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/onderbord"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="6-18h"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVmax"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/tvVmaxOnderbord"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_vmax"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="120"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1321)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:316)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:337)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2397)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15562)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1401)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1121)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are missing the stack-trace :)

Answer (score 2):

I looked thought your xml and it doesn't look like you have any circular references, if as you say you are setting some views as gone I'd take a look at `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` you can find an example [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)

I'd also try not setting any of your views as gone and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: The problem is I can't reproduce the Force Close. The View.GONE could be the problem. I have A, B above A and C above B. B can get View.GONE but on my own devices I don't get FC

Comment: so what I'd recommend is when you set view B to alignWithParentIfMissing, then if B is gone anything referencing it will reference it's references.

Comment: Stacktraces from FC from users, through custom exceptions handler and some crash reports in the developer console.

Comment: No prob. That's definitely worth a try. I'll let you know if that fixes the problem. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem, I even tried adding alignWithParentIfMissing to all views.  I ended up removing all the "stacked" views and created a class extending ImageView in where I dynamically position all the texts. (I was recieving 100+ stacktraces a day, so I had to move fast)  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Usually it happens when you set the view A to be aligned against another view B, and the view B aligned against A, so that makes a circular dependency.

It happens with attributes like above, below, and align when you set the id of another view.

Comment: I've read that, but I can't find any relationship like that in the xml. All relationships between the views are in a one way direction..